# Slow fragment loading (API data binding)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` with a `listview`.

When I click on the `Navigation Drawer` to open this `fragment` it takes 2-3 seconds to load.

I make an API call from `AsyncTask`. I call it from my `onResume()` in my `fragment` because I want to inflate the layout and then call the API and show `ProgressDialog` in opened `fragment` and wait for the `AsyncTask` to finish then populate `ListView`. Problem is that my fragment takes 2-3 seconds(frozen screen) and then loads completely with API call finished and list populated. There is no way to show `fragment` and than populate list. I tried in all `Override` methods in `fragment`. Always the same result. Also when I remove all code from `fragment`, it loads fast.

Any tips why is that happening?

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

        historySearchET = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.historySearchEditText);
        listview = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.historyListView);
        emptyView = v.findViewById(R.id.empty);
            return v;
        }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        historySearchET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.d("aaa", "*** Search value changed: " + s.toString());
                adbHistory.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
                listview.setAdapter(adbHistory);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        APIManager apiManager = APIManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        historyList = apiManager.getUserHistroy();
        adbHistory= new HistoryAdapter (getActivity(), 0, historyList);
        listview.setAdapter(adbHistory);
        listview.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added code.

This is fastest solution that I got worked out. Still 2-3 seconds and frozen screen in meantime. Tried overriding different methods but still same problem, sometimes slower-sometimes faster.

Comment: Post code of your fragment.

Comment: Just post code of your fragment

Comment: I edited question, see code.